# Compare and Remove Duplicate Rows based off TWO columns VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a code where my duplicates will be removed based off of one column. I would like to join column 1 and column 2 as strings (I think that would be the easiest way) and remove the duplicates. Currently I have the code:

```
Range("A1:A6").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

I would like to have it so it compares column 1 and column 2 TOGETHER.

For example Column 1 has:

```
(A1) Apple
(A2) Pear
(A3) Pear
(A4) Apple
```

Column 2 has:

```
(B1) Red
(B2) Blue
(B3) Blue
(B4) Orange
```

In this case, only Row 2 and Row 3 are duplicates. Not Row 1 and Row 4 because you would be comparing two columns instead of one.

Thank you! Hope this made sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the whole range and use `Array` to include both columns:

```
Range("A1:B6").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1,2), Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I know what that means! Wasn't sure of the purpose of Array before.